# Error “TF400998: The current user failed to retrieve the SQL Server service account information” when trying to configure backup plan in TFS 2015

Tags: sql-server, tfs, tfs-2015, windowsdomainaccount

This is a "Answer Your question" type of the post. Just hope the information here will help anyone.

Situation:

- Migrated TFS from Machine A to Machine B
- Restored the DB
- Reconfigured DBs using `TfcConfigure RemapDB`
- Changed service account, url, binding and etc.
- `domainname\TFSService` = service account to run TFS

Problem:

- Logged on as the `domainname\TFSService`
- Tried to setup "Scheduled backups for TFS" using a domain account used as a service account for running TFS ([HOWTO](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh561429(v=vs.120).aspx))
- Back up should be stored on a remote server (accessible over UNC)
- ERROR =  `Error “TF400998: The current user failed to retrieve the SQL Server service account information” when trying to configure backup plan in TFS 2015`

Question:

- How to setup the Scheduled Backup using TFSService account?

Comment: My issue was solved by giving only the SQL Server hostname (DBSVR) rather giving the SQL server instance name (DBSVR\MSSQLSERVER)

Answer (score 2):

Solution:

- Give `domainname\TFSService` account local `Administrator` permissions on Your TFS Server
- Give `domainname\TFSService` account the `sysadmin` role in Your SQL Instance used to run TFS
- Five `domainname\TFSService` account `Log on as a service` permissions on the TFS Server ([HOWTO](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc794944(v=ws.10).aspx))
- **(IMPORTANT!!!)** Run SQL Server Service hosting TFS DBs **AS** `domainname\TFSService` ([HOWTO](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345578.aspx))
- **(IMPORTANT!!!)** Give 'Full permissions' for the account used to run the SQL Service on the UNC destination folder.
- Example: If SQL Server Account = `domainname\TFSService`, than permissions on the UNC should also be given to `domainname\TFSService`

Rerun the TFS "Scheduled Backup" configuration. Should resolve the error.

Sorry if this obvious or straight forward and considered as spam/flooding. Just spent over 3-4 hours. Hopefully this helps people save time and nerves.

Comment: had the same issue. did all of the above mentioned steps (not sure I understand what "UNC denstination folder" refers to, but i'm pretty sure that the account had full permissions on it.
Anyway, in addition to all of that I had to change the SQL service logon user  to be the same user running the TFS service. this is done by opening "services.msc" and changing the logon user of the SQL instance "SQL Server (XXX)"

Comment: @OSH , sorry. [UNC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_(computing)#Uniform_Naming_Convention) - is the format to the folder path where the backups are stored.
What i meant is the folder itself.

Answer (score 2):

In TFS2015 simply make sure that:

1. Make sure `MachineA` and `MachineB` are in the domain and a user "yourDomain\username" is added `Application Tier` >> `Administration Console Users`

[image]

2. `Take Full Backup Now` throw `Scheduled Backups` and move the backup to `MachineB` network share, as a restore process might fail throw network.

[image]

3. Open `TFS Admin console` on `MachineB` and `Remove Application Tier feature` if exists.

[image]

4. Use `SQL Managment Studio` to remove Tfs_configuration and other Tfs_* databases on `MachineB`
5. In TFS Admin Console of `MachineB`, you will have only option to restore under Scheduled Backup.
6. After restoring process on `MachineB`Launch the Application-Tier Only`wizard (right click on Application Tier in TFS Admin Console).In Databases, specify the new SQL Server instance(`MachineB/sqlexpress`) where you restored the TFS databases